# regex using a xml file for search/replace - put a list of <li></li> in a pair of <ul></ul>

Tags: xml, regex, joomla

I am using a xml file for search and replace with Regex - actually it is a Joomla web site, using the component rereplacer. 
I have a list, where I need to add

```
    <ul>
```

for the first

```
    <li>
```

element and close after the last one with

```
    </ul>
```

The xml file is build like

```
    <item>
    <search><span class="SCompany">([^<]*)</span></search>
    <replace><div class="text1">$1</div></replace>
    </item>
```

this. Since I am a real noob when it is about regex, I need some help with this. How is it within the xml file possible, to put all the

```
    <li>content</li>
```

tags into a pair of

```
    <ul></ul>?
```

Comment: Okay - I know that everybody who is about to reply here is MUCH more into this then I am - so I am pretty open to try simple_html_dom again to parse the content within the Joomla articles - is anybody able to give me the start point for this? I once did this in Wordpress without any problem - but Joomla is about killing me (softly...) :)

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are often not a good idea when parsing xml/html, because it is hard to track the syntax.

Regular expressions are most powerful, if the input is one line, and just one line - no context outside.

How do you know, that your li elements all belong to the same list, and not to two or more lists? How to detect li-elements in `<pre>` tags and in comments to ignore them?

Look for an xml-parser instead.

Comment: Well, I tried to work with simple-html-dom - for this would be the best thing I realized when using it before with Wordpress - but now it's Joomla which makes it more difficult to use (may my opinion be only)... I just got no idea, how to load the content in Joomla because it is changing couple of times a week.

Comment: I would say the same thing in much stronger language. NEVER use regular expressions to parse XML, you will always regret it.

Comment: @MichaelKay: No. I used regex often, and I never regret it. HTML is often generated, so if there isn't a line break between start tag and an end tag today, there is maybe none tomorrow. Of course the HTML might change, but whether your xmlstarlet-code or whatever will fit isn't guaranteed. And sometimes I'm myself the source of the html, so I know, if I change it, that I have a script which depends on some assertions. However - I don't manipulate html often, and I'm pretty fluent in using sed, so the investment to learn a new thing might not pay off. Last point: I often see advice: ...

Comment: ... I often see advice 'use xmlstarlet' without specific solution, while the answer in sed is already ready.